# how to display a SWF over a span or div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a swf file with a semi-transparent + tint effect and a HTMl element

`<span id='mybutton'>My Button</span>`

I want to place the swf over the span, so that i can see div/span/a the content through swf.

**Edit 1**
How can i write a JavaScript code to place this swf over the element have `id='mybutton'`. 
If any JQuery code available for this.

Comment: wmode is okey, but what i need is how to show that SWF over there, how to posistion that swf

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `wmode` param to `trasparent` of the flash object.

Comment: wmode is okey, but what i need is how to show that SWF over there, how to position that swf

Comment: @coderex: What do you mean, you mean using `opaque` instead of `transparent`? did you try both of them?

Comment: i need the JavaScript, pls check EDIT 1